# Synonymize tags [gan] and [generative-adversarial-network]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I came across these two tags: [gan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gan) and [generative-adversarial-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generative-adversarial-network).

The [generative-adversarial-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generative-adversarial-network) tag was created first (2018/5/18) and currently has 231 questions.

> Generative adversarial networks (GANs) are a class of artificial intelligence algorithms used in unsupervised (and semi-supervised) machine learning, implemented by a system of two neural networks contesting with each other in a zero-sum game framework.

The [gan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gan) tag was created later (2020/2/7) and currently has 163 questions.

> GAN is a Generative adversarial network

They obviously refer to the same concept and should therefore be synonymized. I checked and there are no active proposals to synonymize them (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gan/synonyms, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/generative-adversarial-network/synonyms). I don't have enough post score on either tags to suggest one, hence this post.

But I'm not actually sure which one should be the master and which one should be the synonym.

I'm not into machine learning, but from what I've read, it's commonly referred to as **GAN** (as an acronym), so making the [gan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gan) tag the master seems more practical. It's also easier to enter "gan" or "GAN" into the tag input field when asking or editing a question . A [quick search of "GAN"](https://www.google.com/search?q=GAN) does not yield any other meanings of that acronym, so I think maybe it's not going to result in any tag collisions.

On the other hand, making the longer tag the master tag also makes sense, since it has a better tag info, has more questions, and it ensures that posts tagged with it *explicitly* refers to "generative adversarial networks". I think it's similar to how the tag [ror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ror) is synonymized with [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails).

Comment: If [gan] is made a synonym of [generative-adversarial-network], then it's still possible to type [gan] into tags field. I vote for the longer, more descriptive tag.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I thought when making a synonym, users can enter [gan] but the post will still render/map it to [generative-adversarial-network], so it should be OK..? But I'm also leaning towards the more explicit, more descriptive tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the list of [40 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgan%5D+-%5Btensorflow%5D+-%5Bpytorch%5D+-%5Bgenerative-adversarial-network%5D+-%5Bdeep-learning%5D+-%5Bmachine-learning%5D+-%22tensorflow%22+-%5Bkeras%5D+-%5Bneural-network%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that weren't tagged with Tensorflow, Keras, Pytorch or any other similar machine learning tags, and found that all of them are related to Generative Adversarial Networks.

While it's true that we usually merge the smaller tag to the larger one, in this case, the tag [generative-adversarial-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generative-adversarial-network) was more descriptive and therefore I used that as the master tag. I've currently synonymized it as:

[gan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gan) (× 261) → [generative-adversarial-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generative-adversarial-network) (× 236)

I will merge the tags after a few days.